# How do I run tkinter in python 3

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to work with GUI on python 3 but I can't get it to work. I get this error message. I have checked the tcl8.6 directory and there is an init file there.

```
import tkinter as tk
tk._test()
```

the error:

```
TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
    {C:\Users\defaultuser0\Anaconda3\tcl\tcl8.6}
```

Comment: you may have a look [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1893)

Comment: I checked it out but did not work. I guess I am missing something.